# Using Time Manager and PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, timemanager

I've just started to use the Time Manage plugin and I was wondering if how compatible it is with PyQGIS. Specifically I was wondering if it was possible to use PyQGis to set up the following features of Time Manage:

- Adding layers
- Setting start time
- Frame length
- Setting unit